# NativeCrashListener: Exception dealing with report when Gridview Scrolling

Tags: java, android, gridview, scroll, crash

please help, when i scroll down the gridview and up suddenly the app goes out i try to see the error log, which i get error like this. Thank you for your help

```
E/NativeCrashListener: Exception dealing with report
                                                      android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
                                                          at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
                                                          at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:169)
                                                          at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:230)
                                                          at android.system.Os.read(Os.java:367)
                                                          at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.consumeNativeCrashData(NativeCrashListener.java:240)
                                                          at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.run(NativeCrashListener.java:138)
```

Comment: post your code. Your gridview and activity code.

Comment: Solve thanks wick.ed, the problem is on the item in the gridview there is a webview, when my webview delete does not happen error like that again. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: So how did you actually fix this? I am having same stack and would like to know why WebView is casing crash and how to fix.